# I want to determine the daily temperature at the administrative level over a long period using R and raster data

Tags: r, function, geospatial, spatial, r-raster

I would like some help to find the best way to determine the average precipitation in several countries at the administrative level. I got the maps from

```
china<-raster::getData('GADM', country='CHN', level=1)
limits.dep<- raster::aggregate(china,'NAME_1')
```

and the data is stored in a .tiff file.

```
data.rain<- function(year){
  print(year)
  dates <- seq(as.Date(paste0(year, "-01-01")), as.Date(paste0(year, "-01-31")), by="days")
  dates <- gsub('-', '.', as.character(dates))
  paths <- paste0(CHIRPS, year, '/', dates, '.tif.gz')
  
  lapply(1:length(paths), function(k){
    download.file(url = paths[k],
                  destfile = paste0('./', basename(paths[k])),
                  mode = 'wb')
  })
}
CHIRPS <- 'https://data.chc.ucsb.edu/products/CHIRPS-2.0/global_daily/tifs/p05/'
data.rain(year=2020)
```

I got a lot of files (daily data) so I am also looking for something that can run for all my files.
I found something online that works but with the large data sets it will take a lot of time to just change the files. I was changing the format from `.tiff` to `.asc` but now that i have more days so I don't think that it is the best way to do it.

The current code that I am using looks like this

```
pacman::p_load(raster, rdgal, rgeos, stringr, sf, tidyverse, RColorBrewer, glue, cowplot, ggpubr, ggspatial, shadowtext)
china<-raster::getData('GADM', country='CHN', level=1)
limits.dep<- raster::aggregate(china,'NAME_1')
mps<- sf::st_as_sf(china)

# this are the results for each month
crn <- list.files('./data/chirps', full.names = TRUE, pattern = '.asc$') %>% 
  grep(paste0(c('januaryRain.asc','FebRain.asc','March.asc','April.asc','May.asc','Jun.asc','July.asc'), 
              collapse = '|'), ., value = TRUE) #%>% 
  stack() %>% #file are raster raster
  raster::crop(., limits.dep) %>% 
  raster::mask(., limits.dep)

# had to run the function because I didn't know how to collect the monthly information from crn 
makeDelta <- function(fls){
  # fle <- fls[1]
  ftr2 <- list.files(fls, full.names = TRUE) %>% 
    grep(paste0(c('januaryRain.asc','FebRain.asc','March.asc','April.asc','May.asc','Jun.asc','July.asc'), 
                #grep(paste0(c('rain.asc'),
                collapse = '|'), ., value = TRUE) %>% 
    stack() %>% 
    raster::crop(., limits.dep) %>% 
    raster::mask(., limits.dep)
  dfr <- crn + ftr2-ftr2 #crn having the information that i need
  return(dfr)
} # I also had to put each data set in different files in one folder and give them the same name
gcm <- list.files('./samename', full.names = FALSE) #folder
fls<- paste0('./samename/',gcm) #full path to each folder
dfr<-map(.x=fls,.f=makeDelta) 

april <- lapply(1:length(dfr), function(k) dfr[[k]][[1]]) %>% 
  stack() %>% 
  mean() 
feb <- lapply(1:length(dfr), function(k) dfr[[k]][[2]]) %>% 
  stack() %>% 
  mean() 
jan <- lapply(1:length(dfr), function(k) dfr[[k]][[3]]) %>% 
  stack() %>% 
  mean() 
july <- lapply(1:length(dfr), function(k) dfr[[k]][[4]]) %>% 
  stack() %>% 
  mean() 
jun <- lapply(1:length(dfr), function(k) dfr[[k]][[5]]) %>% 
  stack() %>% 
  mean() 
mar <- lapply(1:length(dfr), function(k) dfr[[k]][[6]]) %>% 
  stack() %>% 
  mean() 
may <- lapply(1:length(dfr), function(k) dfr[[k]][[7]]) %>% 
  stack() %>% 
  mean() 

mps$gid<-1:nrow(mps)
lyr.china <- raster::rasterize(as(mps, 'Spatial'), jan, field = 'gid')

#results for each province
znl_01 <- raster::zonal(jan, lyr.china, fun = 'mean') %>% 
  as_tibble(.) %>% 
  inner_join(., mps, by = c('zone' = 'gid')) %>% 
  dplyr::select(zone,mean, NAME_1, NL_NAME_1,TYPE_1,mean)
```

If you can improve this code it will be fantastic. If you know different ways to do this I would be so grateful for all your help.

Comment: The raster package is known to be slow, especially when you mask raster data with polygons or rasterize polygons. Two solutions are (i) working with the [terra](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/terra/index.html) package, the raster package's replacement, or (ii) rasterizing polygons with the [fasterize](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fasterize/index.html) package and only masking raster objects with other raster objects of the same crs and resolution.

Comment: And irrespective of that, parallelizing code (e.g. [foreach](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/foreach/index.html) combined with [snow](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/snow/index.html) and [doSNOW](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/doSNOW/index.html) or [parallel](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/parallel/versions/3.6.2) and [doParallel](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/doParallel/index.html)) is usually a good idea.